# How to disable Nvidia GPU in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

This command

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

shows

```
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0

1:DIS: :DynPwr:0000:01:00.0
```

Then , i used

```
echo off > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

But this command is not working . Any suggestions? Also, i do not want to disable my card through the BIOS as i use nvidia on windows .

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable your NVIDIA GPU by using the bbswitch command. Please follow the guide at https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch (too complex to post here)

Comment: Package 'bbswitch-dkms' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-prime' is not installed, so not removed

Comment: I've added to my answer the suggestion to use bbswitch-dkms to disable the NVIDIA GPU (i guess you're having a hybrid GPU laptop). See the link to the package site which explains how it works.

Comment: Sorry, i had to edit my answer because it was misleading to suggest uninstalling bbswitch if it is in fact a possible solution to use it.